# Image Not Displayed in HTML

Tags: angularjs

The Image is not displayed with the below code. But if I can see //xyz.jpg?h=100&w=100 in browser.

What might be missing?

```
<img class="item-thumbnail pointer" data-ng-if="!isPdf()" data-ng-class="{'pointer':showPointer()}" data-ng-src="//xyz.jpg?h=100&amp;w=100" alt="" src="xyz.jpg?h=100&amp;w=100">
```

Comment: Don't use both `ng-src` and `src`. Also, the `//` prefix is used to load a fully qualified URI using the same protocol as the current request, not a relative URL

Answer (score 0):

`data-ng-src="'xyz.jpg?h=100&amp;w=100'"` (string url value)

and

`src="xyz.jpg?h=100&amp;w=100"` (url value)

make sure your image url is `yourdomain/xyz.jpg?h=100&amp;w=100`

You should use `src` in this case.